# change color of inner toggle nav button bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change color of inner toggle nav button like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN5GU.jpg

I searched many articles but found nothing about it.

Comment: One more question: i don't want to use navbar-default or navbar-inverse color, how to change them into transparent or white color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggle nav buttons in bootstrap are spans wrapped in a button object. Just need to change the background color of those span objects.

Try this...

```
span.icon-bar {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: NOTE: only use !important for testing. Your custom styles should overwrite the bootstrap inherited styles.

Comment: One more question: i don't want to use navbar-default or navbar-inverse color, how to change them into transparent or white color?

Comment: If you want to do it properly, create a custom bootstrap theme for yourself. There are a few websites around that will help you generate a bootstrap theme via a WYSIWYG interface.
However if you just need a quick fix....
.navbar-default {
background-color: red;
}

Replace default with inverse if using the inverse base theme :)